# Aurelia Google SignIn Button

Tags: javascript, aurelia, google-signin, google-oauth

I just started using Aurelia and I am having a problem with Google Sign in. It looks like I might be able to create my own Google button but I'd rather get it to work this way if it is possible. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
...
<body aurelia-app="src/main">
...
<span id="googleButtonPlaceholder" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></span>
```

I have the function setup in my Aurelia class but I do not know if/how I can call it. I have tried `${onSignIn()}` which just calls the function when it loads, `${onSignIn}`, `onSignIn()`, `onSignIn`, `data-onsuccess.bind="onSignin()"` but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to pass the Aurelia function to the Google `data-onsuccess` attribute?

As a note, I am switching from Angular 1.5.8 where this previously worked.

Comment: Passing the function reference is probably giving you fits at the moment because it is not a globally defined function so google doesn't know how to locate it.

Comment: That was part of the problem. Google loaded before the template loaded so it was not yet defined. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=5da90f48b43b9c5867c8d2ace0f6371f**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="google-signin-button"></require>

  <google-signin-button success.call="signinSuccess(googleUser)"
                        error.call="signinError(error)">
  </google-signin-button>

  <h1>${message}</h1>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  message = 'Not signed in.';

  signinSuccess(googleUser) {
    const name = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
    this.message = `Signed in: ${name}`;
  }

  signinError(error) {
    this.message = `Error: ${error}`;
  }
}
```

**google-signin-button.js**

```js
import {inject, noView, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

const googleSigninClientID = '927519533400-mfupo3lq9cjd67fmmvtth7lg7d8l50q9.apps.googleusercontent.com';

function preparePlatform() {
  // https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

  // The name of the global function the platform API will call when
  // it's ready.
  const platformCallbackName = 'setGooglePlatformReady';

  // An "API ready" promise that will be resolved when the platform API 
  // is ready.
  const ready = new Promise(  
    resolve => window[platformCallbackName] = resolve);

  // Inject the client id meta tag
  const meta = document.createElement('meta');
  meta.name = 'google-signin-client_id';
  meta.content = googleSigninClientID;
  document.head.appendChild(meta);

  // Inject an async script element to load the google platform API.
  // Notice the callback name is passed as an argument on the query string.
  const script = document.createElement('script');  
  script.src = `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=${platformCallbackName}`;  
  script.async = true;  
  script.defer = true;  
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  return ready;
}

const platformReady = preparePlatform();

@noView()
@inject(Element)
export class GoogleSigninButton {  
  @bindable success = googleUser => { };
  @bindable error = error => { };
  @bindable scope = 'profile email';
  @bindable theme = 'dark';
  @bindable width = 240;
  @bindable height = 50;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    platformReady.then(this.renderButton);
  }

  renderButton = () => {
    gapi.signin2.render(this.element, {
      scope: this.scope,
      width: this.width,
      height: this.height,
      longtitle: true,
      theme: this.theme,
      onsuccess: googleUser => {
        console.info(googleUser);
        this.success({ googleUser });
      },
      onfailure: error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.failure({ error });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is a good solution that works! I found another way of doing it using a slightly different approach that still doesn't require me to make my own Google button. I ended up using the different approach but yours is perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Awesome example!

Answer (score 1):

@JeremyDanyow had a great answer but after I went to bed and read a little more about Aurelia, I thought of a solution to try before seeing his answer so I thought I'd share an alternate approach for those interested.

**index.html**

```
<main aurelia-app="src/main">
</main>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <span id="my-signin2"></span>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
attached() {
   this.render();
}

render() {
   gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
      'scope': 'profile email',
      'theme': 'dark',
      'onsuccess': this.onSuccess,
      'onfailure': this.onFailure
   });
}

onSuccess(googleuser) {
  let gUser = googleuser.getBasicProfile(),
      id_token = googleuser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}

onFailure(error) {
   console.log(error);
}
```

This approach differs slightly from what Google shows on their website where they have you give platform.js an onload function to render the button. Instead, I create the button in the template and then once the template is done being loaded, `attached()` is called, which in turn, calls the function I would have had platform.js call `onload`.

Comment: By not using the onload callback, there is a slight chance that the async load of the google platform api script has not completed by the time the component's attached method is called. This is unlikely to happen, I'm sure google's api script loads extremely quickly.

Comment: You are correct. That is something I was worried about which is why your answer is probably the better way. Something I thought about was trying to put the Google script at the top of the page and make it load synchronously.

Comment: Even simpler!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `data-onsuccess.call="onSignIn()"`.

Comment: You are correct that `call` should be used. I actually tried that and mistakenly put `bind` in my post. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

After following @JeremyDanyow's example around a few corners I came up with this

It works ok for simple usage, but needs help...

1. when there is another window open using a google login there is an error loading something in the iframe google adds (this doesn't seem to break it)
2. the listeners don't work for more than a couple of login/logouts at most

Here's hoping that someone else can improve upon this.

google-signin-button.js

```
import { inject, noView, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

import { LogManager } from 'aurelia-framework';
const Console = LogManager.getLogger('google-signin-button');

// Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app
// https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference
// https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

// inspiration: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button
function preparePlatform(): Promise<Function> {
  // Inject an async script element to load the google platform API.
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=gapi_ready`;
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  // return a promise that will resolve with the onload callback
  return new Promise(resolve => window['gapi_ready'] = resolve);
}

@noView
@inject(Element)
export class GoogleSigninButton {

  @bindable authenticated = (signedIn: Boolean) => { };
  @bindable authorized = (GoogleUser: any) => { };

  @bindable scope = 'profile email';
  @bindable clientId = 'none';

  @bindable theme = 'dark';
  @bindable width = 240;
  @bindable height = 50;

  public element: Element;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  public wasAuthenticated: Boolean;
  sendAuthenticated(signedIn: Boolean) {
    if (signedIn !== this.wasAuthenticated) {
      this.authenticated(signedIn);
      this.wasAuthenticated = signedIn;
    }
  }

  public wasAuthorized: any;
  sendAuthorized(googleUser: any) {
    if (googleUser !== this.wasAuthorized) {
      this.authorized(googleUser);
      this.wasAuthorized = googleUser;
      this.sendAuthenticated(true);
    }
  }

  attached() {
    // inject the script tag
    preparePlatform()
      .then(() => {
        // load the auth lib
        // Console.debug('gapi created, loading auth2');
        window['gapi'].load('auth2', () => {
          // init the auth lib
          // Console.debug('gapi.auth2 loaded, intializing with clientId:', this.clientId);
          window['gapi'].auth2.init({
            client_id: this.clientId
          })
            .then(
              (googleAuth: any) => {
                // Console.debug('gapi.auth2 intialized');
                // listen for user signed in/out
                googleAuth.isSignedIn.listen((signedIn: Boolean) => {
                  // Console.debug('googleAuth.isSignedIn.listener', signedIn);
                  this.sendAuthenticated(signedIn);
                });
                // listen for who signed in
                googleAuth.currentUser.listen((googleUser: any) => {
                  // Console.debug('googleAuth.currentUser.listener', googleUser);
                  this.sendAuthorized(googleUser);
                });
                // draw the button
                window['gapi'].signin2.render(this.element, {
                  scope: this.scope,
                  width: this.width,
                  height: this.height,
                  longtitle: true,
                  theme: this.theme,
                  onsuccess: (googleUser: any) => {
                    // Console.debug('gapi.signin2.render success', googleUser);
                    this.sendAuthorized(googleUser);
                  },
                  // drawing button failure
                  onfailure: (error: any) => {
                    Console.error('gapi.signin2.render failure', error);
                  }
                });
              },
              // intialization error
              (errObj: any) => {
                Console.error('gapi.auth2.init -> errObj', errObj);
              }
            );
        });
      });
  }
}
```

some-usage.js

```
import environment from '../environment';

import { LogManager } from 'aurelia-framework';
const Console = LogManager.getLogger('Login');

import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { AuthService } from 'aurelia-authentication';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

import './login.scss';

@inject(AuthService, EventAggregator)
export class Login {

  public authService: AuthService;
  public eventAggregator: EventAggregator;

  public googleSigninClientID: string = 'none';

  constructor(authService: AuthService, eventAggregator: EventAggregator) {
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    this.authService = authService;

    this.googleSigninClientID = environment.googleSigninClientID;
  };

  isAuthenticated(signedIn: Boolean) {
    Console.warn('isAuthenticated', signedIn);
  }

  isAuthorized(googleUser: any) {
    Console.warn('isAuthorized', googleUser);
  }

}
```

some-usage.html

```
<template>
  <require from="../resources/elements/google-signin-button"></require>
  <section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <center>
        <google-signin-button client-id.bind="googleSigninClientID" authenticated.bind="isAuthenticated" authorized.bind="isAuthorized"> </google-signin-button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```